# Telegram can get chat by id, can't by @name: Chat not found

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

So I've made a bot using @BotFather and I messaged it from my account. Then I found out the id of my account using @userinfobot and sent this request:

`https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id=id&text=test`
and it works fine `ok:true`.

However if I try to use my @username instead of id:

```
https://api.telegram.org/botTOKENg/sendMessage?chat_id=@username&text=test
```

I get an error:

```
{
    "ok": false,
    "error_code": 400,
    "description": "Bad Request: chat not found"
}
```

Looking at my past code, the `@` method used to work for me before. Have things changed?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the id, you cannot use the username.

Giving the username as parameter does only work for public channels.

Have a look at the [Telegram Bot API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmessage):

> **Description**
>   Unique identifier for the target chat or username of the **target channel** (in the format `@channelusername`)

Comment: I took a look and it says you can pass a `@username` string. And I send message to a user like that earlier.

Comment: No, you did read wrong @parsecer "Unique identifier for the target chat" _OR_ "Unique identifier for the target chat".

Answer (score 1):

you can't send message with username you should to use of bot updates and get from_user or effective_user then access to id (chat_id)

- you can't send message to user who never used your bot.

after user doing some action in your bot now you can find and send every thing you want

```
import requests
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, Filters

def pure_api(chat_id, text):
    # don't forget to set bot + TOKEN
    r = requests.get(f"https://api.telegram.org/botTOKEN/sendMessage?chat_id={chat_id}&text={text}")
    print(r.json())

def start(bot, update):
    user_id = update.effective_user.id
    print(user_id)
    bot.send_message(user_id, "any message you want")
    # or 
    update.message.reply_text("any message you want")
    pure_api(user_id, "any message you want")


def main():
    """Start the bot."""
    updater = Updater(TOKEN)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("start", start))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change: chat_id = @myname fro a number de id.
example: chat_ id = 43672587.
this number  you get.
1.- enter  telegram
2.- search @userinfobot and enter
3.-In automatic you get you id

Comment: Check this "Cheat-Sheet" on how to make your code look nice; https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help
You can always edit your answer.